# I don't really understand &

Tags: pure-function

While I use the `&` all the time when doing a mapping, such as

```
someFunction[#] &/@ somelist
```

I don't really understand what it's doing.

I wanted to generate a list of `RandomReal` numbers.  I realize that the `RandomReal` function itself could create such a list, but I wanted to see how the `Array` function handled it.  So at first I tried:

```
Array[RandomReal[], 3]
```

and got

```
{0.211826[1], 0.211826[2], 0.211826[3]}
```

Then I tried:

```
Array[RandomReal[] &, 3]
```

This gave me what I wanted:

```
{0.748657, 0.422851, 0.247495}
```

I also saw that if I tried:

```
Array[RandomReal[#] &, 3]
```

It seemed to map `RandomReal` onto the list {1,2,3} - even though I didn't use `/@`.

Can someone explain to me what's happening with this syntax?  Even though I can use it, I don't understand why, or how it works.

Comment: `Array[expr, 3]` generates `{expr[1], expr[2], expr[3]}` ***after*** evaluating `expr`, just like `Map[expr, Range[3]]` as you noticed. If `expr` is a function, then `expr[1]` etc. will be evaluated.  If `expr` is `RandomReal[]`, it first evaluates to a random number like `0.211826`, which is then used as if the number were a function.  You probably wanted `Table[RandomReal[], 3]`.  `Table` holds its argument, so it will be evaluated three separate times, yielding three different random numbers.  (Basically, I'm thinking it's `Array` that's confusing you, not `&`, but I could be wrong.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array[f,3]` is basically equivalent to `Map[f,{1,2,3}]`. Since `Array` does not have any `Hold`ing attribute, it first evaluates the first argument. Evaluating `RandomReal[]` yields a single random number. So `Array[RandomReal[], 3]` does this:

```
f=RandomReal[]
Map[f,{1,2,3}]
```

> 0.211826
>
> {0.211826[1], 0.211826[2], 0.211826[3]}

Next: `Array[RandomReal[] &, 3]`. Now, we have

```
f = RandomReal[]&.
```

`FullForm[f]` shows that this is `f = Function[RandomReal[]]`. `Function` has the `HoldAll` attribute so that `RandomReal[]` gets *not* evaluated until `f` is called with an argument. So `f[1]`, `f[2]`, `f[3]` will all yield a different random number (between `0` and `1`). Hence `Array[RandomReal[]&,3]` returns a list of three random numbers.

The third one: `Array[RandomReal[#]&, 3]`

Well, `RandomReal` is already a function (not a `Function`, though) and so `f = RandomReal[#]&` is equivalent to `Array[RandomReal[#1]&, 3]`. That means no matter how many arguments you supply to `f`, it will only use the first one and hand it over to `RandomReal`. When called with a single argument like in `RandomReal[3]`, `RandomReal` will return a random number between `0` and `3`. So, `Array[RandomReal, 3]` returns a list of random numbers in which the first one is between `0` and `1`, the second one is between `0` and `2`, and the third one is between `0` and `3`. I use `SeedRandom` in the following in order to highlight that:

```
SeedRandom[123]
Array[RandomReal, 3]
```

> {0.455719, 1.95565, 2.82964}

What you probably want is obtaining a list of `3` random numbers between, say, `-1` and `1`. To this end, you should use the two-argument version of `RandomReal`:

```
RandomReal[{-1,1},3]
```

Comment: Thank you - I didn't get that the `&` basically added `function`.  I see now that If I do `Function[RandomReal[]]` it gives me what I want.

Comment: You're welcome!